Use the WhatsApp-session of selenium on EC2
This is my code where i am initialising the selenium driver
the input for this function is /path/to/WhatsApp-session
def init_driver(user_data_dir):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1280,1024")
    
    # macOS Chrome binary location
    chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
    
    # Set user data directory for session storage
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={user_data_dir}")
    
    # Set up driver with ChromeDriver manager
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    return webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

I am storing the session on my local system, and I want to use that session data to be re-used on EC2 to bypass QR login and automate the service using Whatsapp Web on selenium.
I tried this approach on my Mac, it was working fine, but that session data on EC2 is not working as intended
